# Which approach is better for saving the error in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, ssis, etl, bids

I use **SSIS** for transferring the data and I use **SQL server 2016** I need to use some lookup component in my **DataFlow** task and if I can't find the matches, I should save the record as information in one table. 
That means if for each Lookup component I can't find the related record I have to save that row in a table.

I have to type of DataFlow design and i would like to know which one is better than other?

You can see the DataFlow design in below Images.

In this pattern I use two separate **OLE DB Destination** but in both, I am saving the information in the same Table. 
[image]

In this Pattern I use the Union All Component to union all records and save them in the same time in Destination table.
[image]

I would like to know which design is better than another and what is the pros and cons of each design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better performance and other things, it is better to use `UNION ALL` because:

1. `UNION ALL` is opening one connection with the database (other case a connection is opened for each oledb destination)
2. If the package fails on `LookUp 1` data resulted by `Lookup` will be inserted to the `OleDB Destination` and the package fails, so when restarting the data may be reinserted.
3. It is not a good idea to create multiple `OLEDB Destination` for the same Table, it will decrease the performance due to the *(Table Exclusive-Lock)* each insert will wait others to be done

Comment: Second to that. Adding - **OLE DB Destination** is extra fast with Table locking, which implies single destination.